# asp.net run .bat file on another server

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I have a web app and an .exe with same functionality on serverA that produces a file on a shared folder on serverB. All the logic is inside a dll that is being used by those 2 applications and it produces a file on shared folder and a .bat file that copies the generated file locally, encrypts it and send it back to shared folder.

On serverB the only user that has access to shared folder is SYS\username whereas in my serverA i logged in as local\admin.

When I run the .exe application the dll works fine and produces the final encrypted file on shared folder. But, when i use the web app the dll produces the unencrypted file and the .bat file on shared folder but it is unable to execute the .bat file to produce the final encrypted file.

On application pool on IIS the identity is set to SYS\username. I have also tried with local system but then i receive "access is denied" error when tries to produce the files on the shared folder. Any ideas?

Comment: The directories must have the same user as pool, and privilege to run/write.

Comment: @Aristos the SYS\username has not a local profile set up on serverA. Is that the case?

Comment: create the same account/password to both servers and try it